# Access specific timer to stop it by tag

Tags: c#

Im starting multiple timer with this Code.
All timers run the same Tick_event where i identify the Timer by tag.

```
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.Tag = ID;
        t.Interval = 60000;
        t.Tick += tm_Tick;
        list.Add(t);
        t.Enabled = true;
        t.Start();
    }
```

And on tick event i get the tag ID number with this code, and it works great.

```
private void tm_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((sender as Timer).Tag);
    }
```

But how can i access the specific timer with the ID, to stop it?
its .NET Winforms

Comment: Why is people voting my Question down? whats wrong with it?
I searched stack and did not finder an answer and then i go make one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a Dictionary

```
Dictionary<String, Timer> list = new Dictionary<String, Timer>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.Tag = ID;
    list.Add(ID, t);
    ...
}
```

Then to stop it:

```
list[tag].Stop();
```

Note: Make sure you **Dispose** your timers at some point